# How use PDEmodelica for 2D?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Can I use PDEModelica for calculations in 2D domains. How many domains PDEModelica supports, or DomainLineSegment1D only?
I use OpenModelica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not.
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/pdemodelica.html

PDEModelica1 is nonstandardised experimental Modelica language extension for 1-dimensional partial differential extensions (PDE).